# Grammatik in "ein der größten" oder "eins der größten"

Tags: grammar, usage, article

Ein typischer Satz:

> Kanada ist **eines** der größten Länder der Welt.

Jedoch erscheinen nicht wenige Ergebnisse, wenn man im Google "[ein der größten](https://www.google.de/?gws_rd=ssl#q=%22ein+der+gr%C3%B6%C3%9Ften%22)" oder "[eins der größten](https://www.google.de/?gws_rd=ssl#q=%22eins+der+gr%C3%B6%C3%9Ften%22)" sucht. Sind diese zwei Phrasen grammatisch? Würde man sie in der schriftlichen Sprache verwenden? In der mündlichen Sprache?

Comment: "ein (ohne Endung) der größten" kann nicht vorkommen. Es ist eine Endung notwendig, die den Bezug auf ein Substantiv m/f/n angibt.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"eines" ist hochsprachlich.
"eins" ist realsprachlich.
"ein" ist falsch.

Das häufige Auftreten von "ein" lässt sich wohl wie folgt begründen: Internet, Chat und so.
Zumindest in Kombination mit einem männlichen Nomen ist es wohl ein Faulheitsfehler, denn man spricht ja oft "ein'n".

Answer (score -5):

[Eines](http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/eines) --> Genitiv

Eines ist korrekt.

Kanada ist ein Land. Nominativ.
Kanada ist eines der Länder unter den größten Ländern der Erde.

"Ein der größten." Ist klar ein Schreibfehler.

"Eins der größten." --> So wird eines verkürzt in der Umgangssprache ausgesprochen.

Eines ist allerdings die korrekte Schreibweise.

Comment: In diesem Kontext ist "eines" kein Genitiv, sondern der Nominativ Neutrum des pronominal verwendeten Artikels.